# ref.current.contains(event.target) not working as expected

Tags: reactjs, next.js

So i have this hook that does something every time the document is clicked. but i want it to exclude a reference to the dom node of my choosing.

```
const useClickOutside = (cb: () => void) => {
  const domNodeRef: any = useRef(null);
  useEffect(() => {
    const handler = (event: Event) => {
      console.log("target: ", event.target);
      if (domNodeRef.current && !domNodeRef.current?.contains(event.target))
        cb();
    };
    document.addEventListener("mousedown", handler);
    return () => document.removeEventListener("mousedown", handler);
  }, [cb]);
  return domNodeRef;
};

export default useClickOutside;
```

but for some reason every time it reaches

```
if (domNodeRef.current && !domNodeRef.current?.contains(event.target))
```

it does not work as expected. it works on some places and it doesn't work on many places and i have checked every `event.target` wherever i click and i never get an unexpected DOM node.
yet my condition does not work as expected... but when i grab each element form the `Elements` tab in chrome and write the condition in the chrome console it always behaves as expected.

Comment: `if(ref.current && !ref.current?.contains(event.target)` is not valid code.  Please post the whole code

Comment: @possum i edited my question and added more context to it.

Comment: Try to use `click` event instead of `mousedown` event

Answer (score 0):

Your custom hook takes a single value which is the callback so it doesn't know what element you want to exclude. You need to pass a second argument `ref` and wherever you use that hook you need to pass it the ref of the element you want to exclude. Here is a working example (Although not in TS)

```
import { useEffect } from "react";

export const useOnClickOutside = (ref, handleClick) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    const listener = (event) => {
      if (ref.current && !ref.current.contains(event.target)) {
        handleClick(event);
      }
    };

    document.addEventListener("mousedown", listener);
    document.addEventListener("touchstart", listener);

    return () => {
      document.removeEventListener("mousedown", listener);
      document.removeEventListener("touchstart", listener);
    };
  }, [ref, handleClick]);
};

export default useOnClickOutside;
```

In the example below `doSomething()` will trigger any time you click anywhere except for the referenced button

```
import { useRef } from 'react';

const Component = () => {
  const btnRef = useRef();
  useOnClickOutside(btnRef, () => doSomething());

  return(
    <button ref={btnRef}>
      Referenced Button
    </button>
  );
}
```